# Getting null value

Tags: java, android

I am using com.android.internal.telephony API's. In that I called two abstract classes they are Call.java and Connection.java. You can find these classes here http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/Call.java.html and http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/Connection.java.html for these created subclasses like

```
Call myCall = new MyCall();
Connection myConn = new MyConnection();
```

I need to use getDisconnectCause method from connection class which is an abstract method, I used like this:

```
myConn = myCall.getEarliestConnection();                            
      if(myConn == null){
         System.out.println("myConn is null ******");   
        }else
           {
            Connection.DisconnectCause cause = myConn.getDisconnectCause();                      
                System.out.println("value of cause ******"+cause);  
           }
```

The subclass of Call.java is:

```
1.     CallManager cm = CallManager.getInstance();  
2.        Phone.State state;
3.    
4.        public List<Connection> getConnections() {    
5.         state = cm.getState();       
6.         ringingCall = cm.getForegroundCalls();    
7.         System.out.println("**inside getConnections="+state);    
8.         System.out.println("**inside getConnections="+ringingCall);  
9.           if ( ringingCall == null) {
10.               System.out.println("**call is null***");
11.               return emptyConnections;
12.            }
13.            else
14.            {
15.             System.out.println("**call is not null***");
16.                    return ((Call) ringingCall).getConnections();    
17.            }
18.                    @Override
19.                    public Phone getPhone() {
20.                     return null;
                    }
                   @Override
                   public void hangup() throws CallStateException {

                            }

                   @Override
                   public boolean isMultiparty() {
                    return false;
                   }        
                   public Connection
                       getEarliestConnection() {
                            List l;
                                long time = Long.MAX_VALUE;
                                Connection c;
                                Connection earliest = null;

     68.                        l = getConnections();

                                if (l == null) {
                                    return null;
                                }else if ( l.size() == 0)
                                {
                                    return null;
                                }

                                for (int i = 0, s = l.size() ; i < s ; i++) {
                                    c = (Connection) l.get(i);
                                    long t;

                                    t = c.getCreateTime();

                                    if (t < time) {
                                        earliest = c;
                                        time = t;
                                    }
                                }

                                return earliest;
                            }

                        }

AND the Connection.java subclass is:


    class MyConnection extends Connection{

            @Override
            public void cancelPostDial() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public String getAddress() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Call getCall() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getConnectTime() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public long getCreateTime() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public DisconnectCause getDisconnectCause() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getDisconnectTime() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public long getDurationMillis() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public long getHoldDurationMillis() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public int getNumberPresentation() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public PostDialState getPostDialState() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String getRemainingPostDialString() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public UUSInfo getUUSInfo() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void hangup() throws CallStateException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean isIncoming() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void proceedAfterWaitChar() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void proceedAfterWildChar(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void separate() throws CallStateException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            } 


        }
```

`EDIT 2 : I have edited line number 1 to 17. Plz check this. I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections error on Line No: 16 and Line No:68.` Can anybody help me to resolve this. And also I am getting only one state of call i.e IDLE always even though the call is not-null . I am getting inside else part. plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override
 public List<Connection> getConnections() {
    return null;
 }
```

This method on your `MyCall` class returns null and in your code for `MyCall.getEarliestConnection();` it returns null if `getConnections()` returns `null`.

Comment: Then what should I do? how to implement getConnections method. plz help me. Thx in advance

Comment: I suspect there are implementations of Connection and Call that you can use instead of creating your own try looking on Google

Comment: Had a quick look myself `com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager` may hold what you are looking for.

Comment: You there ?? I need one more help from you

Comment: Hmm I haven't used these classes before and i don't think you completely got my point from before I don't think you want to create your own my call class you simply want to use an implementation of it so. The code you added may be correct but you have added it to the wrong place. I would use the CallManager instead of instancating MyCall, i.e. at the line `Call myCall = new MyCall();` I would have the code you added and have `Call myCall = cm.getActiveFgCall()`. As for it still being null, is there an active call when you are calling `cm.getActiveFgCall()`.

Comment: I would suggest looking for some documentation on CallManager and how to use it as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6482/discussion-between-shiv1229-and-james)

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of the `getConnections()` method has it returning null.

As you can see from the code inside `getEarliestConnection()`, if `getConnections()` returns null, then `getEarliestConnection()` will also return null.

Here is the relevant code:

```
@Override
public List<Connection> getConnections() {
   return null;
}
```

...

```
l = getConnections();
if (l == null) {
return null;
}
```

Comment: Thx for ur reply. How to implement getConnections method

Comment: The whole point of extending an abstract class is that you have your own custom behaviour in mind. If you don't know what behaviour to implement, you should probably not be implementing an abstract class. Look for a pre-existing implementation or something, but I cannot tell you how to implement a *custom* implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this code is supposed to do, but it's clear why that is null at that point.

In "MyCall.getEarliestConnection()", it calls it's own "getConnections()" method, which just returns null.